# Copy a file and append a timestamp

Tags: shell-script, date, file-copy, timestamps

I've got two issues with my script that copies files and adds a timestamp to the name.

```
cp -ra /home/bpacheco/Test1 /home/bpacheco/Test2-$(date +"%m-%d-%y-%T")
```

The above adds `Test2` as the filename, but I want it to keep the original source file's file name which in this example is named `Test`.

```
cp -ra /home/bpacheco/Test1 /home/bpacheco/Test2-$(date +"%m-%d-%y-%r")
```

The other issue is when I add the `%r` as the timestamp code I get the error stating that target "PM" is not a directory. I'm trying to get the timestamp as 12-hour clock time.

Comment: Adding AM/PM add extra space in the filename. If you insist to have it try something like: cp -ra /home/bpacheco/Test1 "/home/bpacheco/Test2-$(date +%m-%d-%y-%r)"

Comment: Or `date +"%m-%d-%y-%I:%M:%S_%p"`

Comment: For a classic Y-m-d_H-i-s + timezones: `"newfile_$(date '+%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S%z(%Z)')"`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

One of your problems is that you left out the double quotes around the command substitution, so the output from the `date` command was split at spaces. See [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters) This is a valid command:

```
cp -a /home/bpacheco/Test1 "/home/bpacheco/Test2-$(date +"%m-%d-%y-%r")"
```

If you want to append to the original file name, you need to have that in a variable.

```
source=/home/bpacheco/Test1
cp -a -- "$source" "$source-$(date +"%m-%d-%y-%r")"
```

If you're using bash, you can use brace expansion instead.

```
cp -a /home/bpacheco/Test1{,"-$(date +"%m-%d-%y-%r")"}
```

If you want to copy the file to a different directory, and append the timestamp to the original file name, you can do it this way — `${source##*/}` [expands](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) to the value of `source` without the part up to the last `/` (it removes the longest prefix matching the pattern `*/`):

```
source=/home/bpacheco/Test1
cp -a -- "$source" "/destination/directory/${source##*/}-$(date +"%m-%d-%y-%r")"
```

If `Test1` is a directory, it's copied recursively, and the files inside the directory keep their name: only the toplevel directory gets a timestamp appended (e.g. `Test1/foo` is copied to `Test1-05-10-15-07:19:42 PM`). If you want to append a timestamp to all the file names, that's a different problem.

Your choice of timestamp format is a bad idea: it's hard to read for humans and hard to sort. You should use a format that's easier to read and that can be sorted easily, i.e. with parts in decreasing order of importance: year, month, day, hour, minute, second, and with a separation between the date part and the time part.

```
cp -a /home/bpacheco/Test1 "/home/bpacheco/Test2-$(date +"%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")"
cp -a /home/bpacheco/Test1 "/home/bpacheco/Test2-$(date +"%Y-%m-%dT%H%M%S%:z")"
```

Comment: Gilles, the first command will not work IMHO, check the positions of double quotes. And see my comment to the question

Comment: @RomeoNinov What's wrong with the first command? Did you run it and get an error?

Comment: You are right, date command is executed in subshell

Comment: Gilles, using your above example, how would I copy the file with the above mentioned timestamp information to another directory. The following command does not work: `cp -a /home/bpacheco/Test1/Test{,"-$(date +"%m-%d-%y-%r")"} /home/bpacheco/Test2`

Comment: @Brian I'm not sure I've understood your comment, but see my edit.

Comment: Gilles, what I mean is when I use your command `cp -a /home/bpacheco/Test1{,"-$(date +"%m-%d-%y-%r")"}` it only copies the file within the source directory. Where in that command do I specify the destination directory?

Comment: @Brian That command with the braces is a shortcut for `cp -a /home/bpacheco/Test1 /home/bpacheco/Test1"-$(date +"%m-%d-%y-%r")"`. If your command doesn't have this form, because you want the destination not to start with `/home/bpacheco/Test1`, then you can't use braces, you need to spell it out, like in my other examples.

Comment: For SOURCE variable I needed to use uppercase letters to get it working!

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' How can I achieve this when,the file path is a command line argument like $1 or $2 and I don't wanna mess up the file extension ?

Comment: @VickyDev I don't know exactly what you want, but try building on this: `directory="${1%/*}"; base="${1##*/}"; extension=${base##*.}; base=${base%.*}`. Note that this simple approach doesn't handle the case where `$1` ends with a slash (designating a directory) or when it's a file name with no extension. In zsh, you can use `$1:h`, `$1:t:r` and `$1:e` which handle these cases correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If the original file name were test1.txt, this copy statement copies it and concatenates a date-time stamp onto the original file-name in the current directory:

cp test1.txt{,.$(date +%Y%m%d%H%m%s)}

the same format string (the part following the "+") can use the "%r" as suggested by others, but the time format that +r yields is "HH:MM:SS AM|PM" and I prefer no embedded blanks or colons.

attribution: this is not my own creation, I found it in a comment somewhere here, in a comment on an unrelated topic.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/424203)